# Incorrect count when counting objects in AWS S3 bucket using sdk

Tags: java, scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am counting the number of objects in `AWS S3` bucket using Scala like this:

```
val reqAws:ListObjectsV2Request = new ListObjectsV2Request().withBucketName(awsBucketName).withPrefix(prefixForAws);
var resultAws:ListObjectsV2Result = null;
var totalFilesInAws:Int = 0;
do {
  resultAws = awsS3Client.listObjectsV2(reqAws);
  val summariesForAws:java.util.List[S3ObjectSummary] = resultAws.getObjectSummaries()
  totalFilesInAws = totalFilesInAws + summariesForAws.size().toInt
  val token:String = resultAws.getNextContinuationToken();
  reqAws.setContinuationToken(token);
} while (resultAws.isTruncated());
```

However it gives me `count` for those prefixes as well that do not contain any objects.

For example, if my prefix is `a/b/c` and my S3 has following structure:

```
bucketName/a/b/c/d/obj1

bucketName/a/b/c/e/obj2

bucketName/a/b/c/f/
```

Now here we can see `a/b/c/f` does not have object but `a/b/c/d` and `a/b/c/e` does have objects, so the `count` should be 2 but my code gives count as 3.

How do I modify my code to get the correct `count`?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon S3 does not actually have folders/directories.

For example, you could run this command:

```
aws s3 cp foo.txt s3://my-bucket/a/b/c/foo.txt
```

This works even though the path `a/b/c` does not exist.

Then, if that object is then deleted, the path disappears.

This is because the filename ('Key') of each object is the **full path**. Amazon S3 makes it 'look like' there are directories, but there really are none.

So, what happens when you create a folder? The answer is that the system creates a zero-length object with the same name as the path.

In your case, there is a zero-length object called `/a/b/c/f/`. This makes the directory appear (even though there is no such thing as a directory).

While `a/b/c/f/` might not *contain* an object, there *is* an object called `a/b/c/f/`.

How to solve this? Here's some options:

- **Do not create directories**. Let them automatically 'appear' through the creation of objects in a given path. This way, there will be no zero-length files of the name of the directory.
- **Change your code** to ignore zero-length objects.

Comment: I need to do it programmatically using Scala or Java

Comment: Yes. Your code can either ignore zero-length objects, or you could simply delete the zero-length objects.

Comment: Okay, how can I code ignore zero-length objects? Can you please suggest me the changes?

Comment: You get the size (amongst other things) in the results from `listObjectsV2`.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following code changes and now I get the correct count

```
val reqAws:ListObjectsV2Request = new ListObjectsV2Request().withBucketName(awsBucketName).withPrefix(prefixForAws);
var resultAws:ListObjectsV2Result = null;
var totalFilesInAws:Int = 0;
do {
  resultAws = awsS3Client.listObjectsV2(reqAws);
  val summariesForAws:java.util.List[S3ObjectSummary] = resultAws.getObjectSummaries()
  for(k <- summariesForAws.asScala) {
    if(!(k.getKey.toString().endsWith("/"))) {
      totalFilesInAws+= 1;
    }
  }
  val token:String = resultAws.getNextContinuationToken();
  reqAws.setContinuationToken(token);
} while (resultAws.isTruncated());
```